# Upload Image, Resize, Modify, Download with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

For the most part this is working, except the uploaded image resizes back to its original size within the canvas when text is added. I'll post a couple of example images below for a visual.

Here is the JavaScript:

```js
 function upImage(imageFile) {
     let imgInput = document.getElementById('imageIn');
     imgInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
         if(e.target.files) {
             let imageFile = e.target.files[0]; //here we get the image file
             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
             reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                 gImgObj = new Image(); // Creates image object
                 gImgObj.src = e.target.result; // Assigns converted image to image object
                 gImgObj.onload = function(ev) {
                     var myCanvas = document.querySelector('.memeCanvas'); // Creates a canvas object
                     var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d"); // Creates a contect object
                     var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
                     var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;
                     var width = gImgObj.width;
                     var height = gImgObj.height;
                     if (width > height) {
                         if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                             height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                             width = MAX_WIDTH;
                         }
                     } else {
                         if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                             width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                             height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                         }
                     }
                     myCanvas.width = width;
                     myCanvas.height = height;
                     myContext.drawImage(gImgObj, 0, 0, width, height);
                 }
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<input id="imageIn" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" onclick="upImage(this)" onchange="runMemeEditor()"/>
```

Here is what the initial uploaded image looks like:

[image: Uploaded Image]

Here is what happens when the editor overlay changes:

[image: Image After Meme Editor Changes]

The call to `runMemeEditor()` simply loads a few functions which displays a Meme Generator. Like I said, it technically works as designed, but the uploaded image when larger than 800x600 end up resizing back to its original size within the canvas.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: (if you are using a backend) Why dont you use an npm package like "shape", its best for image processing, it will reduce your code significantly!!!.

Comment: Thank-you Jatin.  I'm still learning so I will look at this package and see if I understand enough to implement it.